# Turn a DataFrame with multiple rows into a DataFrame with one row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1 | 2 |
| y | 2 | 4 |
| z | 3 | 6 |

What I want is:

| A_x | A_y | A_z | B_x | B_y | B_z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 4 | 6 |

Is there a method in Python that allows me to do this? I tried pivot but I don't have an index - I only need one row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple way, using `unstack` and reworking the columns:

```py
df2 = df.unstack().to_frame().T
df2.columns = df2.columns.map('_'.join)
```

output:

```
   A_x  A_y  A_z  B_x  B_y  B_z
0    1    2    3    2    4    6
```

Answer (score 3):

Since @mozway had my exact answer here a different way:

```
df.unstack().to_frame().T.set_axis(
    ["_".join([a, b]) for a, b in pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, df.index])],
    axis=1,
)
```

---

Try:

```
dfi = df.unstack().to_frame().T
dfi.columns = dfi.columns.map('_'.join)
dfi
```

Output:

```
   A_x  A_y  A_z  B_x  B_y  B_z
0    1    2    3    2    4    6
```

Comment: :D we got synchronized!